# python installing and using pyuwf in a virtual environment

Tags: python

I'm trying to install and use pyufw in a virtual environment for python 3.11.2

The environment setup and pip install goes well, but I get errors when I try to import pyufw

```
(.env) pi@raspberrypi1:~ $ which python pip
/home/pi/.env/bin/python
/home/pi/.env/bin/pip

(.env) pi@raspberrypi1:~ $ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.0.1
pyufw      0.0.3
setuptools 66.1.1

(.env) pi@raspberrypi1:~ $ 

(.env) pi@raspberrypi1:~ $ python
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyufw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyufw/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyufw import *
  File "/home/pi/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyufw/pyufw.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ufw.frontend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ufw'
>>> 
[3]+  Stopped                 python

(.env) pi@raspberrypi1:~ $
```

I have checked for aliases using which and the output shows I am using the environment python and pip.

I tested a different package in the viurtual environment (pypng) but it installs successfully and imports successfully.

EDIT:
I am on a system that won't allow pip installs.  The distribution suggests using venv.  But the venv does not have access to the "ufw" package which comes with the system ufw.  I got around it by using system python and adding the venv's pyufw directory.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyufw')

import pyufw as ufw
```

This does not seem the correct way to do it, so I won't post it as the solution, but it works.

Comment: Did you tried to install `ufw` ? Maybe the package `pyufw` is not well-packaged and doesn't specify well its requirements

Comment: It seems that "ufw" in the system's pip list is part of the (not python specific but implemented in python) package, and unless pyufw is also installed at system level,  it can't use ufw.  I am barred from installing system pip things (>= Bookworm).  So I might have to change from using pyufw to using ufw directly

Comment: Have you tried installing `python-ufw` from your distro's repository?

Comment: The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyufw/) says to run the script that uses `pyufw` in ADMIN mode. Meaning, instead of opening `python`, try doing `sudo python` ? Also, it says that you have 2 different pip installs depending on your OS : `ufw` or `python-ufw`. Have you tried both ? You should `pip install` one, and `pip uninstall` it before installing the other one.

Comment: @antaz the distribution has no python-ufw in any form, so it can't be installed via apt.

Comment: @IMCoins the distribution doesn't allow pip installs at the system level - only in virtual environements.,  Meanwhile the ufw python package (not pyufw... I mean the ufw python package that comes with ufw itself, and pyufw needs to import itself) is only accessible in the system python and cannot be installed in the virtual environment.

Comment: @emptpod You might be given an impossible task then. :)